# Enable/Disable chrome extension from java desktop application

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension which does particular job and tries to connect back to a java desktop application.

Now what I want is, the chrome extension should get enabled only when desktop(java) application is opened and similarly it should get disabled whenever I close the desktop application.

**Can I manage this using java?**

**Or any other way/ CMD is it possible?**

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you would need some ways to exchange message between extensions and native apps, for this purpose, there are many optional ways, such as [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), [WebSocket](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/), or simple http server/client.

Depends on what you choose to use, the implementation details may differ. However their ideas are similar:

1. Start the connection from extension and keep the connection for each side
2. Save a flag in extension side to mark whether your extension should be enabled
3. Once the connection is lost, revert the flag and disable the functionality of the extension

Comment: I am able to exchange message(data). But I want either
**My extension should keep track whenever desktop app is launched it should get enabled and ready to send data.**


Or


**My desktop should itself enable the extension whenever desktop app is launched and get data from extension. And when I close the desktop app it should disable the extension.**

Enable/Disable like in **chrome://extensions/**  from here

Comment: @PankajShinde, to disable extension itself, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782790/how-can-my-chrome-plugin-disable-itself-via-javascript. However you may want another extension to control that logic since obviously you can't enable an extension in its own logic when it has been disabled.